# Using On/Off Checkbox Sliding Switch to Run SQL Query

Tags: php, html, checkbox, mysqli, isset

I am using a simple On/Off sliding switch to update a field in my database.

I turn it "on" no problem, but allowing the user to turn it "off" seems to be giving me trouble. I have multiple switches on this page, so whenever I "submit" it will turn "on" values to "off" unless I remove the elseif statement.

It seems the code considers the $_POST['check-twitter'] to be "isset" when it is on, but "!isset" when I switch it from on to off.

If I change my code to instead be "elseif(!isset....)" then when I come to the page again, it does not recognize the "on" position as being "isset" so it automatically turns it off. It seems inconsistent to what is considered "isset" and "!isset".

I want the switch to only update the database when the user changes it, and I need the switch to show the user whether it is "on" or "off."

```
// $twitter_check represents the field from the database which equals 'Yes' or 'No'

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check-twitter" <?php echo $twitter_check == 'Yes'?'checked':''; ?>>
  <div class="slider"></div>
</label>

if(isset($_POST['check-twitter']) && $twitter_check == "No"){
    //SQL UPDATE $twitter_check = 'Yes'
    } elseif(isset($_POST['check-twitter']) && $twitter_check == "Yes") {
    //SQL UPDATE $twitter_check = 'No'
    }

<input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Save"/>
```

Comment: where/how did you define `$twitter_check`? there isn't enough code here and if there is indeed a post method used.

Comment: @Fred-ii- As I stated in my post, $twitter_check represents the field from the database which equals 'Yes' or 'No'. There's obviously more code on my page showing the SQL query and the form, but it's not relevant to understanding the issue I'm experiencing, and I'm only trying to present the code where the issue exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working...

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM XXXXXXX WHERE user_id = $id";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$twitter_check = $row['auto_post_twitter'];
$facebook_check = $row['fb_auto_post'];
$schedule_check = $row['weekly_email'];

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        // CHECK TWITTER
        if(isset($_POST['check-twitter']) && $twitter_check == "No"){
        $sql_twitter = "UPDATE XXXXXXXX SET auto_post_twitter = 'Yes' WHERE user_id = $id";

        $result_twitter = mysqli_query($connection, $sql_twitter);
        $row_twitter = mysqli_fetch_array($result_twitter);

        } elseif(!isset($_POST['check-twitter']) && $twitter_check == "Yes") {
        $sql_twitter2 = "UPDATE XXXXXXXX SET auto_post_twitter = 'No' WHERE user_id = $id";

        $result_twitter2 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql_twitter2);
        $row_twitter2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result_twitter2);
        }

        // CHECK FACEBOOK
        if(isset($_POST['check-facebook']) && $facebook_check == "No"){
        $sql_facebook = "UPDATE XXXXXXX SET fb_auto_post = 'Yes' WHERE user_id = $id";

        $result_facebook = mysqli_query($connection, $sql_facebook);
        $row_facebook = mysqli_fetch_array($result_facebook);

        } elseif(!isset($_POST['check-facebook']) && $facebook_check == "Yes") {
        $sql_facebook2 = "UPDATE XXXXXX SET fb_auto_post = 'No' WHERE user_id = $id";

        $result_facebook2 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql_facebook2);
        $row_facebook2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result_facebook2);
        }

        // CHECK WEEKLY SCHEDULE
        if(isset($_POST['check-weekly']) && $schedule_check == "No"){
        $sql_weekly = "UPDATE XXXXXXX SET weekly_email = 'Yes' WHERE user_id = $id";

        $result_weekly = mysqli_query($connection, $sql_weekly);
        $row_weekly = mysqli_fetch_array($result_weekly);

        } elseif(!isset($_POST['check-weekly']) && $schedule_check == "Yes") {
        $sql_weekly2 = "UPDATE foodtruck_user SET weekly_email = 'No' WHERE user_id = $id";

        $result_weekly2 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql_weekly2);
        $row_weekly2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result_weekly2);
        }

        // REFRESH PAGE
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
        }

    ?>

<form method="POST" action="XXXXXXXXX">

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check-twitter" <?php echo $twitter_check == 'Yes'?'checked':''; ?>>
  <div class="slider"></div>
</label><br/>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check-facebook" <?php echo $facebook_check == 'Yes'?'checked':''; ?>>
  <div class="slider"></div>
</label><br/>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check-weekly" <?php echo $schedule_check == 'Yes'?'checked':''; ?>>
  <div class="slider"></div>
</label><br/>

<input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// retrieve checkbox value from db
$check = /* db result (true|false) */;
?>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check-twitter" <?=$check && 'checked' ?> />
  <div class="slider"></div>
</label>

<?php
if($_POST['check-twitter']) {
// sql update checked
} else {
// sql update unchecked
}
?>

<input class="button" type="submit" value="Save"/>
```

- When there are only 2 possible values, **if...else** should be used.
- PHP code must be inclosed in PHP tags.
- $_POST variables can be used as is without reassignment.